# Methods to ioniz air molecules

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, electric-fields, molecules

What are other alternatives ways to ionize air molecules, except the electric field charging and the use of the so-called corona discharge?

Answer (score 2):

A very obvious answer is just to heat the air enough (flame). You can also accelerate electrons with electric field and inject them into air (plasma needles and a lot of commercial and lab plasma setups). Microwaves can be used to create and sustain ionization (think of microwave plasma experiments).
The same goes for other wavelengths that resonate with molecular vibration modes (not necessarily microwaves). These are most commonly used for ionizing air on purpose.

Light of high enough frequency carries enough energy to ionize molecules directly (just knock out electrons). An example is what UV is doing at the top of the atmosphere, or X-rays (even though they mostly pass through). Ultimately, every fast enough particle will ionize molecules it hits (that's why α,β,γ radiation is called ionizing radiation). Even neutrinos sometimes manage to knock into atoms, which is why we can detect them (but this may be the least efficient way for ionization).